# How is Dickens using 'as' in ' ... he didn’t know **as** anybody could say how it was ...'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> - *Well, he couldn’t say how it was; he didn’t know **as** anybody could say how it was; all he know’d was, that so it was.*
>
> ([*Little Dorrit*](https://dickens.thefreelibrary.com/Little-Dorrit/1-12) by Charles Dickens, Chapter 12)

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/as) lists three parts of speech that 'as' appears as:

> **as**
>
> - [adverb]
>
>   used in comparisons to refer to the extent or degree of something.
>
>   *go as fast as you can*
> - [conjunction]
>
>   1. used to indicate that something happens during the time when something else is taking place.
>
>      *Frank watched him as he ambled through the crowd* ...
>   2. used to indicate by comparison the way that something happens or is done.
>
>      *they can do as they wish*  ...
> - [preposition]
>
>   1. used to refer to the function or character that someone or something has.
>
>      *it came as a shock*
>   2. during the time of being (the thing specified).
>
>      *he had often been ill as a child*

But none of these seems to correspond to how Dickens uses the word here. It seems to be a similar usage to 'that' or 'whether', used as what a comment has described as a *complementiser*:

- ' ... he didn’t know **as** anybody could say how it was ...'
- ' ... he didn’t know **that** anybody could say how it was ...'
- ' ... he didn’t know **whether/if** anybody could say how it was ...'

Could anyone explain/confirm the usage of "as" in the above sentence?

Comment: Anjan, **please** take note of how well-written questions are structured. Also, you **must** do research in [more than one dictonary](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available/2574#2574) and **show that research** and **what you do or do not understand** in the question. Once you have [edit]ed in your research, the question might be re-opened.

Comment: Please don't put answers in comments. It defeats the object.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I don't know how the OP is supposed to find out from a dictionary that _as_ in this context means _that_. You need to have read a lot of representations of uneducated speech in Victorian novels to be familiar with the usage.

Comment: @Kate It's possible, albeit unlikely, but there is absolutely no evidence of any research at all, so we don't know what OP found out or didn't find. After a number of similar questions this is tough love.

Comment: While I'd be among the last to say that the CV reason shouldn't have been applied here, I have to add that I consider the string 'know as' / 'know as how' in this usage (cf 'Do you know [as to] who') idiosyncratic, and that I've not come across it in the usual online dictionaries.

Comment: This is about dialect, so absolutely NOT suitable for English learners.

Comment: This is dialect, and "as" means "that" (or possibly "whether"), not "since". When the question is reopened I'll make this an answer.

Comment: This question has been closed for lack of research, not because it's suitable for ELL.

Comment: Where do you suggest he went to research this? "Lack of research" is for when the answer should be obvious to anyone who has done a reasonable amount of research. I don't think that would be the case here. We don't close difficult and obscure questions for "lack of research" even if the OP has not recorded their research.

Comment: @DJClayworth At least one dictionary would help. It *is* in OED, and may be in others. And we do close questions where there is absolutely no evidence of research, but simply a question thrown together and then lobbed in our direction.

Comment: OED isn't free, and I don't think we expect people to have subscriptions to dictionaries.

Comment: @Justin Research has been added, but it's incorrect. This is the dialect _complementiser_ usage of 'as' (compare 'he didn’t know that/whether anybody could explain'). 'Er says as er'll be commin.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Feel free to edit the post. It's a valid question and should be reopened.

Comment: It's ***now*** a valid question since it has research. Hopefully Anjan will take note. And @DJClayworth I'm not expecting anyone to have access to OED. I *am* expecting that they dip into dictionaries to which they do have access, something which they have been asked to do in the past.

Answer (score 2):

This is dialect. Dickens is capturing the lower-class dialect speech, as indicated by the ungrammatical "know’d" (which would be "knew" in normal grammar).

To "know as" something means to "know that" something, or "know if" something, or similar.

> I don't know as she's milked the cows.

> I know as he went there yesterday

> I know as the world be round.

Comment: It's not in most dictionaries but it's in the OED: " VII. Introducing a noun clause.  26. Introducing a noun clause, after *say, know, think*, etc.; = *that* conj. 1a. Also in *as that, as how*. Now English regional (southern) and U.S. regional."